# Simular join do mysql com um array do php

Tags: php, join

Boa tarde pessoal.

Tenho um array bidimensional associativo com os seguintes dados:

```php
[0] => array ( "numArea" => '74', "quant" => 2 )
[1] => array ( "numArea" => '7', "quant" => 1 )
[2] => array ( "numArea" => '34', "quant" => 1 )
[3] => array ( "numArea" => '7', "quant" => 2 )
[4] => array ( "numArea" => '74', "quant" => 5 )
[5] => array ( "numArea" => '7', "quant" => 3 )
```

Eu preciso criar um array juntando as quantidades da mesma área. O resultado que preciso ficaria assim:

```php
[0] => array ( "numArea" => '74', "quant" => 7 )
[1] => array ( "numArea" => '7', "quant" => 6 )
[2] => array ( "numArea" => '34', "quant" => 1 )
```

Não tenho a menor idéia de como fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser feito usando o `foreach` (*não necessariamente, pode usar outros laços*). No meu caso usei a lógica mais propicia que me veio em mente, criar um novo array com as novas informações. Para isso criei uma variável `verificaNumArea` onde será adicionado os `numArea` que determinei como `PK`, nesse caso não irá existir mais que uma `numArea` iguais, com isso em mente fiz uma verificação sempre na primeira linha do laço, que verifica se já existe um código igual ao `numArea` vindo do laço, caso não exista, será criado um novo array com as posições [`numArea` e `quant]`, caso já existe irá recuperar qual a posição do `numArea` na variável `verificaNumArea`, para descobrir de qual posição do `newArr` ele pertence, com isso já pronto, basta fazer o incremente da `quant`, segue o código a baixo.

```
$newArr = []; // Onde ficará o novo array com a somatória dos 'numArea'
$verificaNumArea = []; // Onde ficarão os 'numArea' para verificar as posições para atribuir a soma na 'quant'

//Array com valores
$arr = [
    ["numArea" => '74', "quant" => 2],
    ["numArea" => '7', "quant" => 1],
    ["numArea" => '34', "quant" => 1],
    ["numArea" => '7', "quant" => 2],
    ["numArea" => '74', "quant" => 5],
    ["numArea" => '7', "quant" => 3]
];

// Laço que irá percorrer cada item no array 'arr'
foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    // Verifica se já existe o 'numArea' dentro do array 'verificaNumArea'
    if(in_array($item["numArea"], $verificaNumArea)){
        // Caso existe irá pegar a posição determinada da chave e fazer a soma
        $newArr[array_search($item["numArea"], $verificaNumArea)]["quant"] += $item["quant"];
        // Volta ao inicio e não termina o código a baixo
        continue;
    }
    // Adicionar o 'numArea' na variavel 'verificaNumArea' para realizar verificações e não ocorrer duplicidades de 'numArea'
    array_push($verificaNumArea, $item["numArea"]);
    // Adiciona o no novo array 'newArr'
    array_push($newArr, ["numArea" => $item["numArea"], "quant" => $item["quant"]]);
}
```

---

#### Referências:

- *in_array*
- *array_search*
- *array_push*

[Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)